# Do I need to provide a reference table for boolean columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

If I created a table about a user with a tinyint column with boolean states such as "is_vegan", do I need to provide a reference table to explain these values or is it already self-explanatory?

Comment: `TINYINT` can hold more values than just 0 or 1.  If you are planning on using more than 0 for false or 1 for true, you should.  But if it's only ever meant to be T/F, no - it's widely understood that 0 is false and 1 is true.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in the case of gender I was planning to use char(1) so I had the option of having "m","f" and potentially a third option too.

Comment: Your question is asking about *boolean states*, and *gender* is not a boolean state. What does your comment about that have to do with anything?

Comment: Siyual had mentioned how if I was going to use tinyint for anything more than 0 or 1 I should be careful. I was providing an example of this situation where I'd used char to remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using actual boolean values (setting the data type as bit is a good way to enforce this), then you can make a field fairly instructive through extremely descriptive naming. For example, if the table is named `website_user` and the field is named `confirms_currently_vegan`, then you might interpret this as "my website user confirmed on such and such date that they were indeed a vegan". However, you should be wary of how you interpret `False` values in boolean tables when your fields are not descriptive. If it is false, does that mean they eat meat? Or was that just the default value of your field?

That doesn't mean you shouldn't use booleans, just that you should think about the variety of scenarios that either state might represent.

You can go a long way with descriptive naming in your database, but invariably you will reach a point where you want to document something in a way that the database isn't robust enough to support. I would suggest the use of a formatted data dictionary rather than trying to store all of your descriptions in the database, as this simply clutters your data model and makes the purpose your data less clear (in my opinion).